# Many To Many relation. Get object from currently logged in user

Tags: django

this code:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=199)


class Box(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    food = models.ManyToManyField(Food, blank=True, null=True)
```

**How to get all `food` from  `Box` currently logged in user (`request.user`) in my views function?**

```
def get_food(request, id):
    box = Box.objects.filter(user=request.user, id=id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical way is to define a proper `related_name`:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='foods')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=199)

class Box(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='boxes')
    food = models.ManyToManyField(Food, blank=True, null=True)
```

So you can simply do:

```
request.user.foods.all()
```

Or:

```
request.user.boxes.all()
```

Even without `related_name` you can still do:

```
request.user.food_set.all()
request.user.box_set.all()
```

For more information see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_food(request, id):
    box = Box.objects.filter(user=request.user, id=id)
    food = Food.objects.filter(box=box)
```

Comment: This is one approach, but usually it's "nicer" to follow back reverse relationships with related queries.

Comment: `Food.objects.filter(box=box)`. `Food` model  does not have `box` field

Comment: It is still valid despite this, due to the ManytoManyField in your Box class.  Give it a try.